# Scorm 1.2 Player: Command Line Launch

Tags: command-line, ant, scorm, scorm1.2

Is there a Scorm 1.2 player that can be launched from the command line?

I'm looking to integrate the player into a ant script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCORM is a protocol that specifies how one JavaScript component communicates to another JavaScript component. You could in theory have this communication take place in the context of a command line, rather than the context of the browser, but you'd have to have an LMS that supported this kind of communication. I think it unlikely you'll find a component that will do this.

If you are looking for something to script browser behavior, I'd look into [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It will allow you to do automated testing through firefox. This thread may also be helpful: [Automated Web UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805910/automated-web-ui-testing)

Comment: Thanks alumb, I'll look into it and get back