# which automated web testing framework is kept most up-to-date?

Tags: user-interface, html, automated-tests, ui-automation

Related: [Automated Web UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805910/automated-web-ui-testing)

I'm evaluating ui testing frameworks. It seems like some of them aren't updated very often (esp. Selenium, the core hasn't been updated since 6/2009).

My concern here is that I'll adopt/learn a testing framework that isn't going to be **compatible with HTML5**. I'm working in C# land, so I'd prefer a framework that will output tests in C# (Nunit).

Which UI testing framework is most likely to be kept up-to-date as HTML5 features become more commonplace?

Candidates:

- Selenium
- Molybdenum
- Watin
- Sahi
- ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [WebDriver/Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html). This has wide adoption at many major companies (including Google for example) so isn't likely to go away any time soon. It also has wide support from browser vendors.

Otherwise Watir is also popular.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/htmljavscript.html) for cross-platform cross-browser testing of HTML5 applications.

Historically major updates of RIATest were released every 12-18 months, with minor updates coming out every few months.

(Disclaimer: I am a RIATest team member).