# Automated Test Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing

I am looking automated test tool for testing my website project like NUnit. I used Nunit test tool my last project. Now I have to write new test tool for my new web project. 
Anybody know test tool better than Nunit? or should I use Nunit again?
What is the best automated test tool?

Comment: You should also see these question [best-test-automation-tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354576/best-test-automation-tool).

Answer (score 4):

Check [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio with Coded UI and need to do UI automation, take a look at this link:

http://cuite.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your "C#", "ASP.NET" code using Visual Studio (are you?), why aren't you just using the built in unit testing? I use it with VS 2010 and it works great.

Comment: The build in Unit Test depends on the edition of Visual Studio you use. Only Premium and above supports Unit Testing.

Comment: Andreas, I think you're not totally correct. It's possible to create unit testing projects in the Professional edition (I don't have any experience with the editions below that). However, some advanced tools like coverage analysis are only in Premium and above.

Answer (score 0):

[TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) is really cool. It lets you run your tests inside Visual Studio.

Also [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) offers a nice test runner.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of testing you're going to do. If you're going to create true **unit** tests, then you can use any of *Unit frameworks (NUnit, mbUnit,..) or MSTest for its native integration with Visual Studio.

If you need UI testing automation then Selenium is probably the best known tool. You can check also WatiN.

See also this discussion
[Automated Web UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805910/automated-web-ui-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) with [C# Selenium Client Driver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) as the *browser automation* framework and either NUnit or MSTest as your test runner.